# How to debug sqlplus executable with gdb

Tags: gdb, sqlplus

How to debug sqlplus executable with gdb in linux? I am able to do `which sqlplus` and then `gdb <result found from which sqlplus>`. But I want to debug a sql file, say abc.sql. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

> But I want to debug a sql file, say abc.sql. How can I do that?

You can't, at least not using GDB.

You need to understand [what goes into actually evaluating the SQL query](http://rusanu.com/2013/08/01/understanding-how-sql-server-executes-a-query/): it is parsed, compiled, optimized, and executed.

If you were a `sqlplus` developer, you would know parts of `sqlplus` that are responsible for each of above steps, and would be able to set appropriate breakpoints and observe the intermediate results.

But you probably are not an `sqlplus` developer, and debugging it with GDB is unlikely to be useful.

Comment: How about debugging the ODBC driver it loads?